# How to get filename with the content of the file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have around 50 files that I was to consolidate into one with filename and then the content of that file and then leave one line maybe a dotted line after output of the file for e.g. it should look like this

```
File name -ABC
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Content of the file)
..................... (dotted line after output)
File Name - CDE
xxxxxxxxxxxx  (Content of the file)
...................
```

```bsh
Get-ChildItem C:\temp | Get-Content
```

This script gives me the output not not in the format I want. I can't find a way to get the name of the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is fairly trivial. You just need a `ForEach-Object` loop to process each input file individually and the format operator (`-f`) to inject your data into a template string:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp' | ForEach-Object {
  @'
File name - {0}
{1}
.....................
'@ -f $_.Name, (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw)
} | Out-File 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```